# On the roots of Bernoulli polynomials

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables, soft-question, polynomials

Consider the [Bernoulli polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliPolynomial.html) denoted by $B_n(z)$. Now, start plotting the set of all (combined) complex roots $\mathcal{A}_N$ of $B_n(z)$, say for $n=1,2,\dots,N$ for some enough large $N$. It appears that $\mathcal{A}_N$ branches into several "curves".

> **QUESTION:** Or, does it? If so, what are these curves?

*Request:* Can someone post the complex plot here?

Comment: One reference is https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0703452.pdf.

Comment: @RichardStanley: thank you much for the quick reply with the reference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an animation of the zeros of the first $100$ Bernoulli polynomials, produced using Maple.

[image]

For the number of real roots, see [OEIS sequence A094937](https://oeis.org/A094937) and references there.

EDIT: As requested by Wolfgang, here is a plot of the real roots for even $n$ up to $200$.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the quick and generous response to my request for the plots.

Comment: That is nice! It looks like the real roots essentially oscillate between even and odd degrees. Could you add a plot only for, say, even n?

Comment: Very nice! Can share the code, please? Put it here or link to github or like that...

Comment: plots[display]([seq(plots[pointplot](map([Re,Im],[fsolve(bernoulli(n,z),z,complex)])),n=1..100)],insequence=true);
plots[pointplot]([seq(op(map(t -> [n,t],[fsolve(bernoulli(n,z),z)])),n=2..200,2)],symbol=point,axes=box);